# Running the GUI when the Ubuntu Server is started

Tags: server, show-desktop

I am using Ubuntu Server 18.04.

When the server starts, I run the interface with the `startx` command and start using the interface.

My question is: When I run my Raspberry Pi card, I want it to give the `startx` command directly, that is, to start directly from the interface.

And I want to cancel the username and password entry part in the login.

So, when I power on, I want Ubuntu Server and interface to work directly.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: It sounds like you want to switch from Ubuntu Server (no GUI) to Ubuntu Desktop and have auto-login enabled...   Is this what you're asking?  Yes that's possible (it's what the desktops are for).   Note:  *flavor* desktops are no longer supported for *bionic* or 18.04 as they come with only 3 years of support; so if online you may want to consider that; if it's a desktop or GUI you're asking about - which are you wanting to use/install?

Comment: hello my friend. Ubuntu 18.04 server is installed. When my computer boots up, I type my username and password on the black screen (terminal).

login: ubuntu
password: xxxxx

and then my ubuntu terminal works.

I enter "startx" command in terminal and my xcfe interface comes up.


but i have to do this on every boot.

I want to automate this.

that is, when I turn on my computer, I want the "xcfe" interface to be loaded directly.

Comment: For starters; XFCE reached EOL on 29-April-2021 for 18.04/bionic, as being a *flavor* only 3 years of support exists - so I hope you're offline. When you add desktop packages, you are turning a server into a desktop system, which impacts power, can impact network etc...  Servers are assumed always on so ignore power for the most part; where as desktops are often walked away from so have power save functions enabled. Xubuntu/Xfce however is EOL on *bionic* https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ so auto-starting also adds more security holes... (are you sure you want it for EOL software?)

Comment: Yes, I want the interface to start automatically. What can i do for this?

Comment: What does `systemctl status default.target` from the command line tell you?